# Rockshox Reverb Stealth (B1?): attaching the hydraulic hose

Tags: mountain-bike, dropper

Rockshox Reverb collapsed on itself a few weeks back: turns out the retaining clip rotted and gave away. The Rockshox service "repaired" the dropper and sent it back. In the meantime I purchased and installed a new dropper so the idea is to sell the Reverb. So I'm trying to figure out if the thing is ready to be installed.

Problem is that I cannot figure out how to re-install the dropper because of what appears to be missing parts: as you can see from the photos there doesn't seem to be a way of reattaching the hydraulic hose back to the dropper body.

1. Can anybody confirm this is a B1?
2. Which are the parts missing needed to install the dropper?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as in your photo, I bought a new dropper from Chain reaction as mine had stopped working and they had a serious discount on 2019 B1s it was almost as cheap as a repair kit.  When I got my new one they had incompatible connectors - as in your photo...  My old one (2017) was supposed to be B1 and the new one (2019 old stock) was sold as a B1.  May be they changed the connector mid-term.

Initially I tried to buy the correct parts (the larger threaded end in your picture requires what is called a Short barb assembly) but then as I searched online I realised they are all interchangeable - and simple to do especially if you have the cable for both as was my case.

THE SOLUTION FOR ME:

The hose end assemblies are removable so just remove the coupler part(s), whichever type you have / connectamajig or simple barb nut etc, eventually they all unscrew to leave you with a free pipe end - all exactly the same.  They have different hose barbs but these unscrew too with a tiny torx in the centre of the barb or a spanner depending on type - it is obvious when you get there.  Just swap the end connector assemblies over, bleed and you are good to go.